# Angular 4 - How to load html files based on a condition in a component

Tags: angular

I wanna load a HTML file based on a condition. If my browser width less than 1000px I need to load a HTML, otherwise other HTML file.

I tried with

```
import {
    Component,
    HostListener
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: `{{tmplUrl}}`,
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

    tmplUrl: string = './app.component.html';

    @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
    onResize(event) {
        if (event.target.innerWidth <= 1000) {
            this.tmplUrl = "./app_mobile.component.html";
        } else {
            this.tmplUrl = "./app.component.html";
        }
    }
}
```

Above code not working. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using Dynamic Component Loader in Angular.

Create two components which will have the templates that you want to load dynamically, lets call them MobileComponent and OtherComponent. They will both implement one ParentComponent which is just an interface. Here is their code:

Parent Component

```
export interface ParentComponent {
  someName: string;
}
```

MobileComponent

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {ParentComponent} from './parent.component';

@Component({
  template: `
      <h4>Mobile Template</h4> 
  `
})
export class MobileComponent implements ParentComponent {
  someName = 'mobile';
}
```

OtherComponent

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {ParentComponent} from './parent.component';

@Component({
  template: `
      <h4>Other Template</h4>
  `
})
export class OtherComponent implements ParentComponent {
  someName = 'other';
}
```

Then create a service which will provide these components. Let's call it ComponentService. Here's code for it

```
import { Injectable }           from '@angular/core';

import { MobileComponent }   from './mobile.component';
import { OtherComponent }   from './other.component';

@Injectable()
export class ComponentService {
  getComponents() {
    return {
      'mobile': {
        component: MobileComponent
      },
      'other': {
        component: OtherComponent
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Create an anchor directive, here's code for it:

```
import { Directive, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[anchor-host]',
})
export class AnchorDirective {
  constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }
}
```

Now Create RootComponent which will load your MobileComponent and OtherComponent dynamically. Here's code for RootComponent:

```
import {Component, HostListener, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy, Input, ViewChild} from '@angular/core'
import {AnchorDirective} from './anchor.directive'
import { ComponentFactoryResolver } from '@angular/core';
import {ParentComponent} from './parent.component'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-root',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>in root</h2>

      <ng-template anchor-host>
      </ng-template>

    </div>
  `,
})
export class Root implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {

  private currentTemplate: string = 'other'; 

  @Input() components: Array<any>;

  @ViewChild(AnchorDirective) anchorHost: AnchorDirective;

  constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}

  @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
    onResize(event) {
        if (event.target.innerWidth <= 500) {
           console.log('res1');
           this.currentTemplate = 'mobile';
        } else {
          console.log('res2');
          this.currentTemplate = 'other';
        }
        this.loadComponent();
    }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.loadComponent();
  }

  loadComponent() {
    let component = this.components[this.currentTemplate].component;

    let componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(component);

    let viewContainerRef = this.anchorHost.viewContainerRef;
    viewContainerRef.clear();

    let componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
  }

}
```

Now make your AppComponent look like following:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
      <my-root [components]="componentArr"></my-root>
  `,
})
export class App implements OnInit {
  componentArr = []
  constructor(private components: ComponentService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.componentArr = this.components.getComponents();
  }
}
```

And make your app module look like following:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App, Root, AnchorDirective, MobileComponent, OtherComponent ],
  providers: [ComponentService],
  entryComponents: [ MobileComponent, OtherComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Here is the plunker with what you want:

https://plnkr.co/edit/zff8j5AkHjzJDdwffa70?p=preview

Try resizing the windows to see how it works and changes it's template corresponding to your needs.

You can see more info on it and find out why this works by following the link (+ if you want to inject some data to your components as Inputs you can find examples for this in this page too):
https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Comment: Please share with an example, I am new for Angular 4

Comment: I want a common component and events binding code. Only HTML file is different.

Comment: @Veera you can see the example now. Accept my answer if it really answers your question